# Htaccess Rewrite to remove directory

Tags: .htaccess

I need help creating a rewrite string to remove the ~12345678/ from the following: www.example.com/~12345678/file.

This doesn't appear on every link. What happened is during development links were created using the development url, there are a couple dozen links that appear this way. The rest of the links are fine. I already use a rewrite to remove index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (this will redirect any request for `www.example.com/~12345678/dir/file.ext` to `www.example.com/dir/file.ext`) :

```
RewriteRule ^\~[a-zA-Z0-9]+/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: just to be clear, the ~12345678 is just an example. each development client has a different ~whatever. Will this rewrite rule still work or is it only designed to pull out the numbers? All of these dev urls only have alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I edited my answer for alphanumeric support instead of numeric only